# Где в Linux взять таймер вызывающий события?

Tags: c++, linux, c++14, таймер

Мне понадобился таймер который по истечению какого то времени вызывает событие, например std::function. В Win32 API и в C# я очень часто использовал такие таймеры, но тут сходу их найти не смог -_-. Была идея реализовать такой класс самому запустив поток и всё время проверяя текущее время, но в моём проекте очень важна производительность и мне кажется это не самым разумным решением. Из сторонних библиотек я могу использовать только boost (я знаю, что подобный таймер есть в qt, но его я использовать никак не могу). Подскажите пожалуйста где мне взять в Linux дешёвый с точки зрения производительности таймер на события которого можно подписываться функторами  std::function<___>.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В Linux есть posix функция

```
#include <sys/time.h>
int setitimer(int which, const struct itimerval *value, struct itimerval *ovalue);
```

по обнулению таймера в программу приходит сигнал **SIGALRM**
который можно обработать вашей функцией которую ставят на обработчик сигналов 
используя функцию

```
#include <signal.h>
int sigaction(int signum, const struct sigaction *act, struct sigaction *oldact);
```

Comment: Только следует упомянуть, что действия, доступные из такого обработчика сигналов строго ограничены. В т.ч. нельзя выделять / освобождать память, вызывать большую часть кода из стандарной библиотеки, и т.п. За исключением некоторых особых ситуаций и (очень) старого кода, использования (асинхронных) сигналов следует избегать.

Comment: Большое спасибо, сейчас попробую реализовать.

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать `libevent`

```
#include <event.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

#include <iostream>

void On_Timer(int fd, short id, void * param) noexcept
{
    ::std::cout << "Time" << ::std::endl;
    auto const p_event{static_cast<struct ::event *>(param)};
    ::event_del(p_event); // отписываем событие, циклу больше нечего будет делать и он вернет управление в main
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    auto const p_event_base{::event_base_new()};
    auto const p_event{::event_new(p_event_base, -1, EV_PERSIST, &::On_Timer, ::event_self_cbarg())};
    struct ::timeval tv{1, 0}; // 1 секунда
    ::evtimer_add(p_event, &tv); // подписываем событие
    ::event_dispatch(); // запускаем цикл
    ::event_free(p_event);
    ::event_base_free(p_event_base);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Потом может попробую для себя, но в текущий проект добавить что-то со стороны будет очень тяжело (по бюрократическим причинам).

Answer (score 2):

Камрад @yaroslav дал точный и правильный ответ. Но этот вариант достаточно низкоуровневый. Хотя и не требующий дополнительных библиотек со стороны. Но и обладающий рядом нюансов, связанных с контекстом обработки сигналов (изучите этот вопрос, если будете использовать этот метод).

Вы можете воспользоваться таймерами из libev, допустим.

Или воспользоваться [Asio](http://think-async.com/Asio/) (в виде отдельной самодостаточно библиотеки или из состава Boost). Второе особенно актуально при использовании C++11/14/17/etc.

А если будете работать с графикой через Gtk+/Qt, то у них есть свой функционал, при помощи которого можно решить вашу задачу. ЕМНИП и в glib (которому графига и не нужна) есть что-то подобное.

Comment: FYI, livev != livevent, который упомянут ниже ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать функцию [int timer_create(clockid_t clockid, struct sigevent *sevp, timer_t *timerid);](https://linux.die.net/man/2/timer_create).

В структуре [sigevent](https://linux.die.net/man/7/sigevent) есть поле `void (*sigev_notify_function) (union sigval);` которое может содержать адрес функции, вызываемой  в отдельном потоке при срабатывании таймера.

Comment: спасибо, сейчас попробую это тоже.

Answer (score 0):

Если используется пул файловых дескрипторов в общем цикле обработке с помощью функций `epoll`, `poll`, `select`, можно использовать Linux-специфичный набор вызовов, предоставляемый `<sys/timerfd.h>`.

Сообщения в виде 8 байт через заданные промежутки времени появляются во входном потоке. Пример использования есть в [man timerfd_create](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timerfd_create.2.html), или можете посмотреть [в моей программе](https://bitbucket.org/sercxjo/pducontrol/src/master/sbmd.c).