# Реализация time line с помощью цикла или sleep на Linux

Tags: c++, многопоточность, c++11

Необходимо реализовать класс time line, который будет отсчитывать время через заданный ему интервал. Как лучше это сделать?

1 вариант.

```
void TimeLine::StartInThread()
{
    while(!this->stopped)
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(this->interval);
        this->timestamp++;
    }
}
```

2 вариант.

```
void TimeLine::StartInThread()
{
    while(!this->stopped)
    {
        if(this->cur_timestamp - this->save_timestamp > this->interval)
        {
            this->save_timestamp = this->cur_timestamp;
            this->timestamp++;
        }
    }
}
```

Гарантирует ли 1 вариант, что sleep будет на просыпаться вовремя, например, каждые 25 миллисекунд? Как я понимаю второй вариант будет затрачивать больше процессорного времени.

Answer (score 2):

Если у вас не система реального времени (системы linux и windows таковыми не являются) то первый вариант всегда будет срабатывать чуть позже, а если нагрузка на систему большая то значительно позже. Да, второй вариант будет нехило грузить одно из ядер.

4 месяца назад я тоже [сталкивался](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/819512/%d0%93%d0%b4%d0%b5-%d0%b2-linux-%d0%b2%d0%b7%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f) с подобной необходимостью. Решил вопрос используя аппаратные таймеры.

Comment: Спасибо. Мне бы конечно хотелось в кроссплатформенность. В проекте используется qt и boost asio, поэтому попробую использовать их.